# ADOMD.Net Query Result Is Not Correct

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2017, adomd.net

I'm trying to use the MSSQL Analysis Server. I'm trying to execute a DMX query however the readers result is not in correspondence with the SQL Server Management Studios as the reader throws index out of bounds error.

I have imported "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64" V15.3.1 with NuGet and I'm using SQL Server 2017
Here is the test apps code

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost;Catalog=MultidimensionalProject2;");
        connection.Open();
        AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand("SELECT  PredictAssociation([Association].[v Machine Purchase Stat], 5) From  [Association]", connection);
        AdomdDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<object> asd = new List<object>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           Console.WriteLine(reader[1]); //Index out of bounds error
        }
        reader.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here is the [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyuVc.png) and the result of the [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEbHH.png)

Comment: try `reader[0]`

Comment: I get this Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdDataReader

Comment: try `reader.GetString(0)` or `reader.GetString(1)` instead. Also add C# tag to your post.

Comment: Now I get Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaDataReader for reader.GetString(0) and the same Index out of bounds exception for reader.GetString(1)

Comment: Also wrap your connection, command, and datareader in Using statements.

Comment: @gv260ea maybe you need to use `FLATTENED` ? like `SELECT FLATTENED PredictAssociation([Association].[v Machine Purchase Stat], 5) ....etc `

Comment: I have tried `SELECT FLATTENED  PredictAssociation([Association].[v Machine Purchase Stat], 5) From  [Association]` and now `reader[0]` throws the Index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it apperantly the reader had another reader in it which represented the second step from the tree.
Here is the working code.

```
 using (AdomdConnection connection = new AdomdConnection("Data source=localhost;initial catalog=MultidimensionalProject2;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (AdomdCommand command = new AdomdCommand("SELECT PredictAssociation([Association].[v Machine Purchase Stat], 5) From  [Association]", connection))
            {
                using (AdomdDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {                        
                    List<object> asd = new List<object>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var r2 = reader.GetData(0);
                        while (r2.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(r2[1]);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary Close calls.

Comment: For info: the two calls to `Close` are redundant since they are called internally by the implicit Dispose as the code exits the two respective `using` blocks.